# How to handle multiple clients connected to a server in CPP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, server, winsock2

I am trying to learn winsock2 by following a [tutorial](https://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/). The problem is that the last section where it tells you about handling multiple clients, has empty code. How would this be achieved with multi-threading in a nice-mannered way?

Code: https://pastebin.com/D3L8CgAi

```
Since links to pastebin must be accompanied by code, I need to add this.
```

Comment: There are so very many ways to answer this question that it actually would probably be harmful for someone to try.  Please narrow down your question by describing what you've done, and what you've done to figure out how to resolve first, preferably with your sample code.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I have updated my question to have a pastebin link. Hopefully it is useful. Also the same code can be found on the tutorial page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify: I would not use threads to handle multiple clients.

To your question:

- 1 thread should listen for new connections.
- When a connection is accepted a new socket is created.
- For each accepted socket: create a thread for reading/writing to that socket.

The reason I would not implement it this way, is because it will not scale well. After ~100 concurrent connections (maybe more, maybe less) the process will crash due to out of memory. (Threads are expensive).

Google "multi thread socket windows C++" you should find numerous examples including videos with explanations.

If you really want to create a scalable server review libraries such as libevent (which wrap asynchronous mechanisms such as epoll).

Comment: While it is true that 1 thread per client doesn't scale, it will not fail with just 100 concurrent clients, it would take ALOT more clients to do that. A server could easily handle many 100s of clients concurrently, even 1000 clients if you reduce the default stack size a little, before it failed.